# Backport EVP_PKEY_Q_KEYGEN to OpenSSL 1.1

Tags: openssl

I have some code built against OpenSSL 3.0 that I need to backport to OpenSSL 1.1. Unfortunately, one function that doesn't seem to have a direct analogue in 1.1 is `EVP_PKEY_Q_keygen`. How can I reasonably generate an EC private key in OpenSSL 1.1 that I can then use to generate a certificate signing request?

Essentially, I need the equivalent of this:

```
  EVP_PKEY *pkey =
      EVP_PKEY_Q_keygen(NULL, NULL, "EC", (char *)(strstr("prime256v1", "")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old high-level way, similar to what `genpkey` does:

```
EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;
EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id (EVP_PKEY_EC,NULL); if( !ctx ) error;
if( EVP_PKEY_keygen_init (ctx) <= 0 ) error;
if( EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_ec_paramgen_curve_nid (OBJ_sn2nid("prime256v1")) <=0 ) error;
/* even though spelled paramgen this is valid for keygen also */
if( EVP_PKEY_keygen (ctx, &pkey) <= 0 ) error;
```

The old low-level way, similar to what `ecparam -genkey` does:

```
EC_KEY *ec = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name("prime256v1"); if( !ec ) error; 
if( EC_KEY_generate_key (ec) == 0 ) error;
EVP_PKEY *pkey = EVP_PKEY_new(); if( !pkey ) error;
if( EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY (pkey, ec) == 0 ) error;
EC_KEY_free (ec);
```

Error handling left as an exercise, especially since you didn't show any yourself.